# picture rotate after a click on a picture

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    }
```

I click on a picture to flip the other, but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?
I've used pictureBox1 before.

Comment: I think the handler method can't be private try the same with public.

Comment: I've already tried. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code rotates the image. But you still need to update `PictureBox` to display the rotated image.

```
pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```